# unsupported: LAST_INSERT_ID is only allowed for unsharded keyspaces

Tags: mysql, vitess

I am using MySQL on vitess and My java application is running on docker version 19.03. When I add any record in the database table using hibernate, it is showing error

> unsupported: LAST_INSERT_ID is only allowed for unsharded keyspaces.

Not sure why this error is showing as I didn't write anywhere to

```
select last insert id
```

I am adding records through hibernate save() function and didn't used any insert/update query.

Answer (score 0):

We recently expanded support for `last_insert_id`. The latest code should work for sharded keyspaces also. There's still no support for `last_insert_id(val)` yet, only `last_insert_id()`. But it should be coming up soon.

You'll need to vitess 6.0 version.